# Async/Await for tree traversal recursively in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, recursion, async-await, tree

I have the simple tree structure as following:

```
class Group {
  id: ObjectId;
  name: string;
  subGroups: [ObjectId]
}
```

[image: Example Tree Structure]

For example, Group A has two subGroups Group B, C, and Group C has three subGroups Group F, G, H, etc.

I need to implement an algorithm to get all groups recursively:
Expected Output = [Group A, Group B, Group C, Group D, Group E, Group F, Group G, Group H, Group I, Group J]

But I need to fetch the subGroups from the database so that that should be async/await.

Method 1

```js
    const tr = async (group: Group, result: Group[]) => {
      console.log(group);
      result.push(group);
      for (const id of group.subGroups) {
        const groupId = id.toHexString();
        const subGroup = this.findGroup(groupId);
        tr(await subGroup, result);
      }
    };

    const result = [];
    await tr(user.group, result);
    console.log(result);
```

Method 2

```js
  async transverse(group: Group, result: Group[]) {
    console.log(group);
    result.push(group);
    for (const id of group.subGroups) {
      const groupId = id.toHexString();
      const subGroup = await this.findGroup(groupId);
      await this.transverse(subGroup, result);
    }
  }

  const result = [];
  await transverse(user.group, result);
  console.log(result);
```

Method 1 cannot output the correct array, and it does not output the completed Gourp A to J. Method 2 can get the correct array, but the code does not look clean. Does anyone know how to achieve this goal in an elegant way and answer me why method 1 doesn't work?

Comment: You forgot to `await tr(...)`

Comment: `tr` is async so you should await it

Comment: I guess `toHexString` is unrelated to your question, right? Although you were helped by the comments above, I believe there are things that can be improved, so I posted an answer still.

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of some modern features, like an async generator, to do a traversal over your tree.

As in the example you have given, the traversal is breadth-first, I would not go for recursion, but iterate with a loop over each level of the tree. The Group objects can be resolved in "parallel" when they are on the same level, as these results don't depend on each other. This is a good use case for using `Promise.all` instead of individual `await`s for each node separately.

Here is how it could look -- I have included an mock for the database part:

```js
class Group {
    constructor(id, subGroups) {
        this.id = id;
        this.subGroups = subGroups;
    }
}

// Mock of asynchronous DB
const db = {
    _tree: {
        "A": ["B", "C"],
        "B": ["D", "E"],
        "C": ["F", "G", "H"],
        "D": [],
        "E": [],
        "F": ["I", "J"],
        "G": [],
        "H": [],
        "I": [],
        "J": []
    },
    findGroup(groupId) {
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() =>
            resolve(new Group(groupId, db._tree[groupId]))
        , Math.random() * 1000));
    }
};

// Make an async generator
async function * tr(groupId) {
    result = [await db.findGroup(groupId)];
    while (result.length) {
        yield * result;
        // Use Breadth-first traversal order, and allow some parallellism
        result = await Promise.all(result.flatMap(group => group.subGroups.map(db.findGroup)));
    }
};

// Consume the async iterator you get from the above function. The call starts with the id of the tree's root:
(async () => {
    for await (let result of tr("A")) {
        console.log(result);
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so your class looks like

```
class Group {
  id: ObjectId;
  name: string;
  subGroups: [ObjectId]
}
```

We need to define what we need
so,
Expected output is:

[Group A, Group B, Group C, Group D, Group E, Group F, Group G, Group H, Group I, Group J

In other words, we need to loop in the following way:
group -> all children and repeat.

We can use a variable that will hold the next groups and then loop through it.
This variable will be initialized with the first group that you fetch (For example group A) and then the loop will print it name, loop through it children and will save each children to be next on the print-to variable we just made.
After we finish to loop through it children, we will remove the main group.

We will use a while loop that will stop only when nextToPrint variable is an empty array.

```
nextToPrint = []; // variable to hold the next groups to print so it will need to be initialized with groupA.


// some method that runs when your app starting, like mounted() on Vue, attached() on aureliaJS or ngOnInit on Angular
async someMethod() {
  const first = await getGroup(first) // get first group
  nextToPrint.push(first); // push to the queue-like variable


  // loop through the next to print 
  while(nextToPrint.length) {
      printGroup(nextToPrint[0]); // print first item in the next list
  }
}

async printGroup(group: Group) {
   console.log(group.name); // print Group name
   group.subGroups.forEach(g => {
       const child = await getGroup(g); // send it to get the next group
       nextToPrint.push(child); // add child to be the last one to print
       console.log(child.name); // print the child name
   });

   nextToPrint.shift(); // remove first element from the next to print
}
```

Hope it will help, feel free to comment and ask more questions until we get it right

Comment: I try to use your method but I can print out the Group A, Group B, Group C only. Actually, I need to traversal the tree to the array list not only print out. Does this method achieve that?

In addition, is any benefit of your method compared to my original post? Thanks for your answering.

Comment: You're original answer looks just fine, I think something else is wrong there, if you can add some code it can help.
Also, I think in my method you should be able to print all of them, but if you need to stuff rather than printing, just add another method and call it instead of the console.log(child.name)
something like 
doStuff(child)

and in do stuff you can do anything on the child